# How to trigger onhover event by element following cursor

Tags: javascript, css, hover, onhover

I have an element following my cursor and I'm wondering if there's a way to trigger the css onhover event or add a class when the cursor element goes on top of my buttons.

Comment: Note that on stack overflow we help you with your code. we will not teach you how to do something. do some research. Since your question is "is there a way", I will answer it: Yes, there is.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to disable the pointer events on the element that's blocking the pass-through of your cursor.

Try this (CSS):
`pointer-events: none;`

Comment: Will it still follow the cursor if you turn pointer events off? not sure. Also, this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.